# Securing a Subscription WCF Webservice

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, authentication, security

I'm working on a subscription data delivery webservice using C# and WCF. Customers will sign-up to use the service at different usage levels for a monthly fee. The project requirements call for the service to be accessible from a web app hosted on the same server, from a desktop app and Windows service distributed to customers and from a WordPress plugin. In the future, support may be added for other CMS systems and mobile (Apple/Android) apps.

The security requirements include a standard user ID and password authentication for each call to the service to verify subscription status and type and to track user activity. That's easy enough to do but there's more and that's what I'm looking for advice on.

First of all, there's the need to track IP addresses and use this information to control access. One part of this is to restrict the number of different IP addresses the service can be called from within a specific time period per ID and subscription type. The second part is to prevent access to the service from certain countries entirely. I've read some other answers here about how to implement IP address detection/tracking in general but I am more concerned about potential difficulties associated with this that others have encountered. What should we watch out for here?

The second major security requirement is to restrict access to the service to our provided desktop/service applications or from authorized domains using our CMS plugins. I'm not sure how this can be implemented other than using some sort of authentication token which of course could be easily hacked. Perhaps in combination with the login and IP address requirements this will be enough though. Are there any alternative methods that might be a better approach to take?

Comment: For the access to the provided desktop/service applications or from authorized domains using the CMS plugins, I would opt for certificates. You deploy a certificate server on your web farm, and generate certificates for the authorized users. Associated with this deployment model, you have all kinds of facilities to revoke access to users, track them, map them to users on your system, etc. And additionally, you will use SSL/TLS, which can be encrypted traffic. Just to give you some heads on ...

Comment: @kroonwijk - Thanks for that certificate idea. I'll have to see if this will work within our plans.